# What does CSS measurement unit 'em' actually stand for?

Tags: css

As the title says, I want to know what exactly the CSS unit 'em' stands for.
As in 'cm' stands for **c**enti**m**eter.

I am not asking what 'em' is or how it is used!

I couldn't find an answer on [W3C](http://www.w3.org).
The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29) article was already saying "something":

> The name of em is related to M. Originally the unit was derived from the width of the capital "M" in the given typeface.

My interpretation of the first sentence would be that 'em' is the pronunciation/phonetic for the letter 'M'.
But reading the second sentence, it seems that the 'e' in 'em' stands for something regarding the width of the letter 'M'.
So I'm still lost, what 'em' really stands for!

Comment: After seeing all these lousy attempts at answering your question, I feel like I should have closed it instead, because frankly, it's not really on topic for our site. The only thing about your question that makes it remotely relevant to Stack Overflow is the fact that the em unit is used in CSS, but it's not a question *about CSS*.

Comment: @Bolt : I'm with you regarding the lousy answers, but which stackexchange part would you recommend instead?

Comment: We have a site for English language and usage where etymology questions are on topic, but let me first ask the moderators there if they want it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Closing in the meantime. I may reopen and migrate your question and my answer if the English.SE mods want it.

Comment: W3C now has a page about it here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm

Comment: It stands for ephemeral unit.

Comment: @IamBatman won't it be eu then? Ephemeral measurement perhaps?

Answer (score 82):

That is a historical definition; in modern usage it simply refers to the size of the font, with the word "em" itself no longer having any practical or relevant meaning. As a matter of fact, the same Wikipedia article expands on this evolution in its usage and meaning in [a later section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29#Incorrect_and_alternative_definitions):

> One em was traditionally defined as the width of the capital "M" in the current typeface and point size, as the "M" was commonly cast the full-width of the square "blocks", or "em-quads" (also "mutton-quads"), which are used in printing presses. However, in modern typefaces, the character M is usually somewhat less than one em wide. Moreover, as the term has expanded to include a wider variety of languages and character sets, its meaning has evolved; this has allowed it to include those fonts, typefaces, and character sets which do not include a capital "M", such as Chinese and the Arabic alphabet. Thus, em generally means the point size of the font in question, which is the same as the height of the metal body a font was cast on.

Particularly in terms of CSS, an "em" doesn't necessarily refer to the width of the capital M for a particular font; it's just a relative quantity.

If you're asking about the *etymology* of the word "em", Wikipedia itself only contains a reference to the [Adobe Glossary](https://www.adobe.com/type/topics/glossary.html#em), which has little more to say about it:

> A common unit of measurement in typography. Em is traditionally defined as the width of the uppercase M in the current face and point size. It is more properly defined as simply the current point size. For example, in 12-point type, em is a distance of 12 points.

It's not explicitly mentioned anywhere authoritative that it's a phonetic representation of the capital M, but considering its namesake definition I wouldn't rule out such a possibility.

Comment: Even if historical what did 'em' then stand for? Could you point that out more clearly? Thanks.

Comment: @drkthng: You've answered your own question, then: it's the phonetic representation of the letter 'M'.

Comment: I'm not sure though, because that part of the Wiki explanation is without source and using "related to M" is rather vague, isn't it?

Comment: @drkthng: It is, but from the looks of it, it's all we've got.

Comment: completely with you here!

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion em stands for nothing but just pronunciation/phonetic for the letter 'M'. Similarly we have ex, one ex is the x-height of a font (x-height is usually about half the font-size).