# Android Studio : what does ems stands for in android:ems="some number"

Tags: xml, android-studio

I know that ems is a way of determining **Font-Size**.
but the question is , what was the words that abbreviated into **ems**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does CSS measurement unit 'em' actually stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827038/what-does-css-measurement-unit-em-actually-stand-for)

Answer (score 0):

The name of em is related to M. Originally the unit was derived from the width of the capital "M" in the given typeface.

this question was already answered here:
[What does CSS measurement unit 'em' actually stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827038/what-does-css-measurement-unit-em-actually-stand-for)

Answer (score 0):

An "em" is a typographical unit of width, the width of a wide-ish letter like "m" pronounced "em". ex 1em = 2in

Answer (score 0):

Its only the size of the box or any widget you use in android studio. no matter what label is written inside it if you decrease its value the size of the box decreases and hence everything will not be visible.